# Labview IMAQ WindDraw External Display Embedding

Tags: image-processing, labview

I am working in labview on using multiple gig-e industrial cameras to display a set of images for a semi-automatic test system with data and human visual inspection.

The main issue that I have currently encountered with the vision software is that screen tearing corrupts the display of the video making it hard to observe the dynamic aspect of the test. There is a VI control called the IMAQ WindDraw external image display that has an anti-tearing option that appears to work but I need to embed 4-5 video displays into one window and not show the title bars/window buttons. Basically I want to tie the external displays to the front panel VI and run them in a windowed full screen mode.

The front panel VI will not need to be scrolled or be resizeable as the system is dedicated to the task.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses one of the Vision DLLs to include an IMAQ WinDraw external display into the front panel of a VI.

Hope this helps.

Ah... as a new user I can't post images... Oh well.

You can use the NIVisWnd.dll (to be found in C:\WINDOWS\system32)  to get the IMAQ WinDraw external image's handle (function name is : GetWindowHandle) and then use user32.dll to make external image child of FP (function name is : SetParent).